# SQL Server ISNUMERIC returning wrong data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. When I execute the following query, ISNUMERIC is evaluating to true(1) when the barcode clearly has 'D' inside it.

```
 SELECT ISNUMERIC('7210300106D30')
```

If I execute the same code with other letter than D or E, it seems to evaluate to false(0) which is what I expect.

```
 SELECT ISNUMERIC('7210300106K30')
```

Can anyone please shed a light as to why this may be happening? Thanks.

Comment: Hexadecimal numbers are 0123456789ABCDEF

Comment: Here is an excellent article on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/

Comment: Interestingly, the reason `D` is accepted by `ISNUMERIC` and `CONVERT` is probably a holdover from FORTRAN, as that's the only language that does anything with this notation, as far as I can tell. This isn't even consistent in SQL Server itself: `1e3` is a literal with value `1000`,  but `1d3` is parsed as the constant `1` aliased to the column name `d3`. `ISNUMERIC` is the gift that keeps on giving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for strings of digits, don't use `isnumeric()`.  Just use `like`:

```
select (case when col like '%[^0-9]%' then 0 else 1 end) as IsAllDigits
```

If you want to try a conversion, then use `try_convert()`:

```
select (case when try_convert(bigint, col) is null then 0 else 1 end) as IsConvertable
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, you first solution is ideal for me

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**

My initial answer is wrong, it is because `e` is used in scientific notation to assign an exponent, and D is used aparently to to notate a number format too.

like `10e3`

> Do notice that "e" and "d" (everybody forgets about this) are not
>   included as numeric in the results because a single "e" or "d is NOT
>   considered to be numeric. HOWEVER, these letters represent two
>   different forms of numeric notation (the one with the "e" is
>   Scientific Notation). So, if you have anything that looks like the
>   following, ISNUMERIC will identify them as "Numeric"...
>
> SELECT ISNUMERIC('0d2345') SELECT ISNUMERIC('12e34')

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/

<strike>It might see it as a hexadecimal number, which is anything within the number sequence:</strike>

```
0123456789ABCDEF
```

> Hexadecimal describes a base-16 number system. That is, it describes a numbering system containing 16 sequential numbers as base units (including 0) before adding a new position for the next number. (Note that we're using "16" here as a decimal number to explain a number that would be "10" in hexadecimal.) The hexadecimal numbers are 0-9 and then use the letters A-F.
>   http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/hexadecimal

Comment: Probably not. replace `D` with `A`, `B`, or `C` you will get 0.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like @Tschallacka's answer is correct. The input is treated as a hexadecimal number.

If it is not expected, you can operate in following way:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(RTRIM('7210300106D30') + '.')
```

Comment: This is a hack on top of the existing mess. Is `5,` numeric for our purposes? According to this trick, yes. What about `-$`? Why of course, that's a money type. If all you want is to exclude letters, then this will do, but usually you just want to avoid `ISNUMERIC` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `TRY_CAST (... as bigint)`

ISNUMERIC is known to be flawed with a dot, a space, the letter E, and several others

```
 SELECT TRY_CAST('7210300106D30' AS bigint)
```

Gives NULL, so it is not numeric

### Update for older versions

Using LIKE and negatives

```
IF '7210300106D30' LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
    PRINT 'broke'
ELSE
    PRINT 'OK'


IF '143618726378451623' LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
    PRINT 'broke'
ELSE
    PRINT 'OK'
```

Comment: `12345678901` clearly is numeric, yet will fail this conversion.

Comment: bigint then. decimal (38,0). It depends what range you expect

Comment: My point is that there is no type in SQL Server that will allow this test as "a string that is a sequence of only digits" for *any* number of digits. If the barcodes in question happen to fit a particular numeric type, then yes, this will do. (Ignoring pesky characters like `-` and `.` and `,`, of course.)

Comment: TRY_CAST in my opinion was introduced in 2012, so it will not work on this instance for me as I use 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Here the TRY_CONVERT is try to convert the value into bigint format
      If the given value is  not pure number  then the TRY_CONVERT return null
 By using 'case' we return unconvertable value as 0 and convertable values as 1

```
 SELECT   
        CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(bigint , '7210300106D30') IS NULL   
        THEN 0  
        ELSE 1
    END AS Value;
```

Comment: Beware: `7210300106030420000` fails (doesn't fit in a `DECIMAL`), `721030010603042.0000` succeeds (even though it contains a period).

Comment: you are right , In that case we can use TRY_CONVERT(bigint, '7210300106030420000')

Comment: TRY_CONVERT in my opinion was introduced in 2012, so it will not work on this instance for me as I use 2008 R2